# Initial state as an object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a following state in React:

```
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A>({});
                              // ^^^ error
```

However Im getting error that Im missing `foo` in the initial state. But I dont have any initial value for `foo` field.

What is the proper way to handle it?

```
useState<Partial<A>>({});

or 

useState<A>({} as A);

or make `foo` optional?

useState<{ foo?: string }>({});
```

What is the correct fix for such situation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this solution is good:

```
useState<{ foo?: string }>({});
```

Other solution is:

```
interface A {
 foo: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A>({ foo: '' });
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I dont want to modify the `A` interface?

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options to fix your issue.

1. Make the foo property optional:

```js
interface A {
   foo?: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A>({});
```

2. Initialize your object with empty string:

```js
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A>({ foo: '' });
```

3. Change the type of your state:

```js
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A | undefined>();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle `undefined` initial state then use `undefined`.

```js
interface A {
   foo: string;
}

const [val, setVal] = useState<A | undefined>();
```

Then you have a good chance to handle `undefined` inside your component.
You also get help from your IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is property of typescript and if val state is using A interface it must have foo property with string value
if its possible for your code to have initial foo value it would be better to add it like this :

```
useState<A>({
  foo:''
})
```

if not, my suggestion is using this syntax :

```
useState<A | undefined>()
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is, it depends on how your app should work. Take a look at possible solutions and decide which is fitting your logic or app context

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=43&ssc=11&pln=44&pc=20#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-aQiRvOSkHvYpqGKGBGEadAqi-QwVTk6NuC-X9pmEWYABZ5jgRYgM7fN3hrb56wHK5hEBfCZyIuc4MXMjyMot1Oh6TMRxzAlnVdGRqMNWiQzDIA